# Как выделить несколько пунктов в QMenu

Tags: c++, qt, windows-10

я добавляю в проект поддержку redo/undo. Мне нужно сделать выделение всех QActions, стоящих выше текущего в выпадающем меню QToolButton. В выпадающем меню находится список действий. В итоге я планирую получить такой-же вид как в VisualStudio:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код создания кнопок (вперед/назад) с выпадающими меню:

```
_undoAct = new QToolButton(this);
_redoAct = new QToolButton(this);
QIcon icon21;
icon21.addFile(QStringLiteral(":/Icons/png/undo.png"), QSize(), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);
_undoAct->setIcon(icon21);
_undoAct->setPopupMode(QToolButton::MenuButtonPopup);
QIcon icon22;
icon22.addFile(QStringLiteral(":/Icons/png/redo.png"), QSize(), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);
_redoAct->setIcon(icon22);
_redoAct->setPopupMode(QToolButton::MenuButtonPopup);
_undoMenu = new QMenu(_undoAct);
_undoAct->setMenu(_undoMenu);

_redoMenu = new QMenu(_redoAct);
_redoAct->setMenu(_redoMenu);
```

Вот то, как это выглядит на данном этапе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не смог найти упоминания setFocus для QAction, метод setActiveAction не дает возможности выделить несколько пунктов меню. Есть ли вообще возможность такое реализовать?

Comment: Можно поменять стиль элемента так, чтобы он выглядел активным.

Comment: Оно больше похоже на Combobox